# oData Paging with Filters

Tags: vb.net, odata

I can query the odata and get the first 50 results I need using Where clauses in my query. I am trying to figure out how to add where clauses when doing paging with the WCF services client. There are a million C# examples out there but I cannot figure out the syntax for vb. So far I have...

```
Public Sub CycleData()

    ' Create the DataServiceContext using the service URI.
    Dim ExigoURI As Uri = New Uri("http://api.Exigo.com/4.0/abc/model", UriKind.Absolute)

    ' Create a new instance of the typed DataServiceContext.
    Dim context As ExigoContext = New ExigoContext(ExigoURI)

    context.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("xxx", "yyy")
    Dim token As DataServiceQueryContinuation(Of PeriodRankScore) = Nothing
    Dim pageCount As Integer



    Try
        ' Execute the query for all customers and get the response object.
        Dim response As QueryOperationResponse(Of PeriodRankScore) =
        CType(context.PeriodRankScores(Query).Execute(), QueryOperationResponse(Of PeriodRankScore))

        ' With a paged response from the service, use a do...while loop 
        ' to enumerate the results before getting the next link.
        Do
            ' Write the page number.
            Console.WriteLine("Page {0}:", pageCount + 1)

            ' If nextLink is not null, then there is a new page to load.
            If token IsNot Nothing Then
                ' Load the new page from the next link URI.
                response = CType(context.Execute(Of PeriodRankScore)(token),
                QueryOperationResponse(Of PeriodRankScore))
            End If

            '' Enumerate the customers in the response.
            For Each customer As PeriodRankScore In response
                Console.WriteLine("CustomerID: PeriodID: RankID: {0} {1} {2}", customer.CustomerID, customer.PeriodID, customer.PaidRankID)
            Next

            ' Get the next link, and continue while there is a next link.
            token = response.GetContinuation()
        Loop While token IsNot Nothing
    Catch ex As DataServiceQueryException
        Throw New ApplicationException(
        "An error occurred during query execution.", ex)
    End Try

End Sub
```

I would like to add something like this...

```
CType(context.PeriodRankScores.Where(Function(a) a.PeriodID = 12).Execute(), QueryOperationResponse(Of PeriodRankScore))
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out if anyone is curious!

```
  Dim query As DataServiceQuery(Of PeriodRankScore) = From PaidRanking In context.PeriodRankScores
                                                        Where PaidRanking.PeriodID = 74 And PaidRanking.PeriodTypeID = 12 And PaidRanking.Score = 100
                                                        Select PaidRanking
                                                        Order By PaidRanking.CustomerID Ascending

    Try
        ' Execute the query for all customers and get the response object.
        Dim response As QueryOperationResponse(Of PeriodRankScore) =
        CType(query.Execute(), QueryOperationResponse(Of PeriodRankScore))
```